# Stored procedure is not getting import in Data Entity Model in VS 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am using Data Entity Model in my project in asp.net 3.5 . I am trying to map stored procedure and those are successfully mapping but they are not showing in my "Entity" class to use. I also checked the xml schema and found "function import","Function import mapping" and "Function" tags in conceptual, map and store schema.

Please let me know what is getting wrong.